# Using WM_KEYDOWN and wParam

Tags: c++, input, key

Noob question here, but I can't find any other threads that answer it. All I want to know is how to use the WM_KEYDOWN message, and then proceed to use its wParam parameter to check which key has been pressed. Like a lot of people, I'm using this to try and get windows to stop with the key-repeat delay.

I can get my program to respond to WM_KEYDOWN with

```
if (WM_KEYDOWN)
    //do something
```

But I can't work out how to access the wParam parameter. The code

```
if (WM_KEYDOWN)
    if (wParam == 'A')
        //do something
```

doesn't seem to work.

This kind of code is way out of my depth, but people are saying it's the easiest way to get around the key-repeat delay. I don't really understand what a message is or how it can have a parameter.

Comment: The condition in `if (WM_KEYDOWN)` is always true. Surely you mean `if (msg == WM_KEYDOWN)`. Checking `wParam` the way you do looks OK to me. In what way, exactly, doesn't it seem to work? What results do you expect, and what do you observe instead?

Comment: The code snippet is too poor to guess what "it doesn't work" might mean.  Boilerplate code is `if (HIWORD(lParam) & KF_REPEAT) // It's repeated`

Comment: Well wParam is always underlined in red and is apparently an undeclared identifier. And now that I try it again, WM_KEYDOWN does indeed seem to always be true.

Answer (score 1):

This is a very old question as there were some changes to MSDN, however I will try to cover the multiple scenarios.

### Scenario A

You're capturing a Message Callback through a Windows Procedure without using [SetwindowsHookEx](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/nf-winuser-setwindowshookexa?redirectedfrom=MSDN). Example: You're capturing messages inside [WNDPROC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/ms633573(v=vs.85)).
First you need to detect the message type as in `(msg == WM_KEYDOWN)`. `msg` contains the event that triggered the call. This way you can utilize `wParam` where it will be the Virtual Key code.

### Scenario B

You're capturing a Message Callback through Low Level Keyboard Procedure ([WH_KEYBOARD_LL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/ms644985(v=vs.85))). In this scenario `wParam` acts as `msg` from `Scenario A`, and `lParam` contains additional info. You'll need to map `lParam` into a [KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/winuser/ns-winuser-kbdllhookstruct) and extract the Virtual Key code from it.
`KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT kbStruct = *((KBDLLHOOKSTRUCT*)lParam);`
You can now access the Virtual Key code by using `kbStruct.vkCode`.

### Scenario C

You're capturing a Message Callback through Keyboard Procedure ([WH_KEYBOARD](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/ms644984(v=vs.85))). In this scenario `wParam` contains your Virtual Key code, and lParam contains the flags. Refer to MSDN for more info the flags. In order to detect Key Down/Up and/or Holding the button, you'll have to rely on the flags on bits 31 and 30 (`lParam>>31` and `lParam&0x40000000`).

Comment: I spent like 3 days to understand the info you wrote. If I see this comment earlier I would literally saved 3 days :) This is all correct it has different behavior for different situations.

Answer (score 0):

As was pointed out in the comments you probably meant to write

```
if( message == WM_KEYDOWN )
```

since

```
if( WM_KEYDOWN )
```

will always be true since it's a constant.

As for the wparam check if I recall correctly you need to compare it to a lowercase character  not an uppercase one.

Comment: And how can I set 'message' to make a return dependent on whether or not a key is being pressed?

Comment: if( message == WM_KEYDOWN ) return a;
else return b;